# Ported Chrome extension to Firefox not working (indexedDB error)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, indexeddb

I'm trying to port the [Twitter Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ikknnkomiokeodcdkknnhgjmncfiefmn) extension to FF.
I'm not too familiar with JavaScript so I just used [extension factory](http://www.extensionfactory.com/labs/conversion/) to convert it to FF.

Unfortunately it is not working; I don't get any HTML5 desktop notifications.
I've looked at the code a bit and I think the problem is with twitter.js which should be found in the path 'resources\extension-data\js'.

http://pastebin.com/C0NqU4Ur

First I've changed

```
twitter.messagesDB = window.webkitIndexedDB.open("messagesDB");
```

to

```
twitter.messagesDB = window.mozIndexedDB.open("messagesDB");
```

but it still is not working. 
The error console also doesn't show any error.

When I put a console.log command to the twitter.messagesDB.onsuccess function nothing is being outputted to the error console. 
Also no output when I create an onerror function. 
So I though to surround the functions with a try and catch clause but no error is being thrown.

So I tried to put twitter.messagesDB = twitter.messagesDB.result; out of the function and the following error shows up in the error console:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations."  code: "6" nsresult: "0x80660006 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEXEDDB_NOT_ALLOWED_ERR)"  location: "chrome-extension://gjlehiopfilnaggndcmbhphaglkbkekf/js/twitter.js Line: 28"]
```

What does that mean?
How can I make it work in Firefox?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm using Firefox 12 on Windows

Comment: The extension factory created a custom `chrome-extension` protocol for your extension. I guess that using IndexedDB on that protocol just isn't possible. That's the issue with automatic conversion services - they try to hide differences between platforms but there are just too many.

Comment: Too bad. I think have to stay with the old version of the extension. It doesn't use IndexedDB and is working. At least the notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an incompatibility between the Firefox implementation of IndexedDB, which supports the latest IndedexDB protocol published December 2011, and the Chrome implementation, which supports the version previous to that.

The breaking change is how databases are created, where the older (Chrome) implementation uses the `setVersion` transaction whereas the newer version (FF) uses an `onupgradeneeded` event and callback.

To see this change, [please star this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108223).

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've starred the issue.